# Ошибка при запросе в MySQL с длиной и началом слова

Tags: mysql

Необходимо вывести список слов начинающихся на S при этом их длина не должна быть больше 5 символов.

Вот мой код: SELECT Word FROM Words WHERE Word LIKE 'S%' UNION SELECT Word CHAR_LENGHT (Word) AS '5' FROM Words WHERE CHAR_LENGHT (Word)>5;

Comment: а ошибка в чём заключается?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да синтаксическая у него ошибка. Он придумал новый синтаксис, а MySQL, собака страшная, его понимать не желает.

Comment: Делает выборку всех слов начинающихся на S

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, почитайте, как работает SQL и как описываются запросы. По большей части запрос не нужно усложнять, как Вы его хотите видеть, так он и пишется.

Ваш вариант:

```
SELECT `word`, CHAR_LENGTH(word) as `length` FROM `words` WHERE `word` like "S%" AND CHAR_LENGTH(`word`) <= 5;
```

Что дословно "Выбрать слова (и длину для себя) из таблицы words, где слово начинается на S и длина слова меньше или равна 5".

И ещё внимательно смотрите, как называются функции. Функции `CHAR_LENGHT` не существует (посмотрите на последние 2 буквы).